# Returning subarray item as array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following php code:

```
$menu_wood = array();
$menu_wood[] = array('link' => 'holz.php',
            'description' => 'Holzübersicht',
            'class' => isCurrentPage('holz.php')
            );
$menu_wood[] = array('link' => 'ahorn.php',
            'description' => 'Ahorn',
            'class' => isCurrentPage('ahorn.php')
            );
$menu_wood[] = array('link' => 'birke.php',
            'description' => 'Birke',
            'class' => isCurrentPage('birke.php')
            );
```

Is there a buildin function in PHP that can return an array of all the 'link' elements, or do I need to write my own function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need to use your own code this way.

```
$myLinks = array();
foreach ($menu_wood as $menu)
    $myLinks[] = $menu['link'];
```

If you wanna write a function, you can do so this way:

```
function getPart($array, $arrIndex)
{
    $myLinks = array();
    foreach ($array as $single)
        $myLinks[] = $menu[$arrIndex];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You use `array_map` to achieve this

```
$links = array_map(function($var){ return $var['link'];}, $menu_wood);
var_dump($links);
```

Output

```
array
  0 => string 'holz.php' (length=8)
  1 => string 'ahorn.php' (length=9)
  2 => string 'birke.php' (length=9
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write your own, like this one:

```
foreach ($menu_wood as &$arr) {
   $links[] = $arr['link'];
}

var_dump($links); //will show all link values
```

Comment: @AndreaKR why did you edited my code to remove the & ? If you don't know what is its purpose it's not a reason to remove it..